# Citrix receiver experiences long delay, disapears for about 3 minutes

Tags: citrix

When invoking the Citrix Receiver from either Firefox or the Citrix Receiver, the Citrix window will flash up quickly then disappear and then after about 3 minutes the VM will appear and all is well. How can I get rid of the long delay?

Comment: I'm also using Citrix Receiver on Ubuntu 13.04 over Internet, I don't have this delay. Did you try from the command line wfica.sh ?

Answer (score 0):

**Please note that this fix will make all your secure connections vulnerable to attacks. Only do this if you know what you are doing!**

The problem is that the citrix client needs a random number to create a secure connection. It asks the random number from your operating system, but the operating system needs three minutes to generate that number. You can shorten this time by using the not-secure random number generator of your system.

Create a symlink like this:

```
ln -sf /dev/urandom /dev/random
```

See the 6th post here:

http://forums.citrix.com/thread.jspa?threadID=246296

I'm utilizing the receiver and this helps out tremendously. I also noticed that it went away after a reboot (Ubuntu install in VMWare Fusion 5).

I created a shell script:

```
/etc/init.d/symlink.sh

#!/bin/bash
ln -sf /dev/urandom /dev/random
```

I then added the pathe (/etc/init.d/symlink.sh) to /etc/rc.local.

Good luck.

Comment: You should keep in mind that this link effectively replaces `/dev/random` with the much less *random* `/dev/urandom` - for the whole system!! see comments #10 and #16 on the forum you linked to.